# MonoGame OpenGL Song Loading Error

Tags: c#, monogame

I am transferring my game from XNA 4.0 to MonoGame OpenGL Porject. When I am trying to Load a Song it threw a weird exception.

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not find file 'D:\Work\0_Menu.wma'."

The project is D:\Work\C#\CleanEmUp_MonoGameGL\

and the files are made Content and Copy if newer and I loaded lots of graphics before it but it loads from two previous folders any help please.

Thanks inadvance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, you can't name your folder C# in OpenGL project but with DirectX its okay :D

Comment: That fixed it for me, too. Thank god for your answer, I would have never thought of that.